# Facebook Login "500 internal server error" in touch mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

We are using the method described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/ to log users to our web site.

It was working fine since the last week. Now what happens is that

- in mobile devices it does not automatically redirect to our site
  after the user logs in.
- Instead, the FB server returns a "500 Internal Server Error" error.
- But this only happens with the mobile version of the login page
  (`option display=touch`), with the desktop version the redirection
  performs well.

This works:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={myAppId}&redirect_uri={myurl}
```

This doesn't work:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={myAppId}&redirect_uri={myurl}&display=touch
```

- As we didn't know if the service was down for whatever reason
- or there was a problem with our FB application,
- we have created another FB application and we have set the web site
  to a known url: **www.google.com**.
- Then we have tested the url:
  `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={myOtherAppId}&redirect_uri=wwww.google.com&display=touch`,
  and to our surprise it worked, resulting in a redirection to the
  google search site.
- But if we set our web site in both the test FB application and the login url, it fails again with the same "500 Internal server error".
- So we suspect that there is something wrong with FB and our domain.
- Could FB be blocking my URL when trying to redirect through the mobile version of the login dialog?
- We would like to contact the FB support team directly by email but we are unable to find a way to contact them.

Can anybody give us a clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's because your app is in Sandbox mode.